# Integral in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, integral

I was wondering if anyone could please let me know the prototype of Integral function in Anylogic. Thanks a lot.

For example, how to put the lower and upper bound of integral?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as an integral, nevertheless, the concept of stock and flow on a system dynamics model is equivalent to an integral

The lower and upper bound are your simulation initial and end time... And if you want to define other lower and upper bounds, you have to make your flows equal to 0 until you reach the initial time and after you reach the final time.

What you are integrating is the sum of the flows that are going in minus the sum of the flows going out of the stock and the result of that integral, is the value of the stock.

Of course, you can only integrate based on time, and using an approximation method such as Euler.